# My code is inserting data even without showing error

Tags: php

The code is inserting data without showing error. Like when I put an image that is higher than 2mb it still submits the data. I do not understand why it is behaving like that.

Here is the code:

```
$err = "";
$db = $user->getDb();
$value = "SELECT * FROM payment_properties WHERE id=1";
$query = $db->query($value) or die($db->error);
$data = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$admin_price = $data['admin_cash'];

if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {

    $admin_id = $user->validate($_POST['admin_id']);
    $p_brand = $user->validate($_POST['pbrand']);
    $p_cat = $user->validate($_POST['pcat']);
    $p_title = $user->validate($_POST['ptitle']);
    $p_price = $user->validate($_POST['pprice'] + $admin_price);
    $p_desc = $user->validate($_POST['pinfo']);
    $p_key =$user->validate($_POST['pkey']);
    $p_qty =$user->validate($_POST['pqty']);
    $image = $user->validate($_FILES['avatar']['name']);
    $tmp_dir = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
    $imgSize = $_FILES['avatar']['size'];


    $upload_dir = '../../product_images/'; // upload directory. My problem

    $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

    // valid image extensions
    $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions

    // rename uploading image
    $image = rand(25, 100) . "." . $imgExt;

    if (in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)) {
        if ($imgSize < 2000000) {
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir, $upload_dir . $image);
            $value = "INSERT INTO products (product_brand, product_cat, product_title, product_price, product_desc, product_image, product_keywords, product_qty, admin_id)
            VALUES ('{$p_brand}','{$p_cat}','{$p_title}','{$p_price}','{$p_desc}','{$image}','{$p_key}','{$p_qty}','{$admin_id}')";
            $query = $db->query($value) or die($this->db->error);
            if ($query) {
                $err = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
                            <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
                            <b>Successfully uploaded</b>
                        </div>";
            } else {
                $err = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                            <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
                            <b>Error sending data</b>
                        </div>";
            }

        } else {

            $err = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                        <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
                        <b> Sorry, Image size should be less than 2mb';</b>
                    </div>";

        }
    } else {
        $err = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
                    <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
                    <b>Only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.</b>
                </div>";
    }
}
```

The remaining errors too are not showing when I test it.

Comment: It will submit the data because you are not checking the file size at frontend. Try taking a look at fineuploader , it has inbuilt methods for file size/type validation

Comment: Do you echo the     $err

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @Parody: I approved your edit, but I was tempted to reject it. It probably is OK in this case, but normally we suggest that code is only tidied lightly, in case an edit changes the nature of the question (or inadvertently hides the source of a bug). It is already the case that the program now outputs more whitespace than the author's version, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function to calculate your image size.

```
$size = getimagesize($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']);
```